# Aggregating raster values for each grid in fishnet-like map

Tags: raster, aggregation

I have a raster layer containing the elevation info., and another gridded layer (shapefile type). What I want to do is to calculate the mean elevation within each grid to have a single representative value.

Does anyone know how to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ArcGIS Desktop, solving this problem involves becoming familiar with the [zonal statistics](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Zonal_tools/009z000000w1000000/) tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using the [v.rast.stats](http://grass.osgeo.org/gdp/html_grass64/v.rast.stats.html) module in GRASS GIS

There is also a faster version of it on the [GRASS AddOns page](http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/AddOns/GRASS_6#v.rast.stats2)